# Investigate if $ f (x)=$ is differentiable. If so, is it $ f '$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

> $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0,x=0 \\ |x|^{\alpha}\sin(\frac{1}{x}),x \neq 0 \end{cases}$$ $$\alpha>0$$

**My try:**
$f(0)= \lim_{ x\to 0^{-}}f(x) = \lim_{ x\to 0^{+}}f(x)=0$ so f is continuous
$f'(0)= \lim_{ x\to 0} \frac{|x|^{\alpha}\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x}$

$f'_{+}(0)= \lim_{ x\to 0^{+}} x^{\alpha-1}\sin(\frac{1}{x})$
$f'_{-}(0)= \lim_{ x\to 0^{-}} \frac{(-x)^{\alpha}\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x}$
However I don't know how I can investigate for which $\alpha$ $f'(0)$ exist.
Can you get me some tips?

Comment: Hint: for limit when $x \to 0^-$ use $x=-y$ and make the limit when $y \to 0^+$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly, without left/right derivatives:

$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}|x|^{\alpha-1}\sin\frac1x=\begin{cases}\text{Doesn't exist finitely} , \alpha-1\le0\iff\alpha\le1\\{}\\0, \alpha-1>0\iff \alpha>1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Ok, but can you tell how you calculate it?

Comment: @MP3129 The sine is bounded, and $\;|x|^{\alpha-1}\;$ tends to zero...or not!